# How to delete the local processes - maven[id]?

Tags: jbossfuse

I am using JBoss Developer studio 10.1.0.GA.
I have a fuse integration project. In my `JMX Navigator` there are so many unused maven[id] formed. How can they be removed/deleted?

Please refer the image.
 [image: snap from JBDS]

Answer (score 0):

Wow, how did that happen? I guess you ran a Camel context locally several times? Did you stop the process in DevStudio console view? That should usually make those processes disappear. In your case there might be several running processes in the console view so stop and close one by one.

Alternatively you could terminate them manually either via the Task Manager (Windows) or by invoking "kill " (Linux).

I would really love to hear what you did to get into that state.